# Differential operator and equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Here is the problem:
I have a certain PDE and there is the nonlinear terme $h$, I have as data:
$f \in H_0^2(0,L)$,,,$g \in {H^1}(0,L)$ with ${g_x}(0) = {g_x}(L) = 0$
Now on consider the fnction  $$h(x) = f'(x)(g'(x) + {(f'(x))^2}){\rm{ }}{\rm{, x}} \in {\rm{[0}}{\rm{,L]}}$$
we notice that $h(0)=h(L)=0$.
It is well known that the operator:$$(I - \partial {}_x^2):H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L) \to {L^2}(0,L)$$ is bounded and invertible, and its inverse defined by:
$${(I - \partial {}_x^2)^{ - 1}}:{L^2}(0,L) \to H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L)$$
the question: have we the inequality $${\left\| {{\partial _x}{{(I - \partial {}_x^2)}^{ - 1}}{\partial _x}h} \right\|_{{L^2}(0,L)}} \le c{\left\| h \right\|_{{L^2}(0,L)}}??$$ ($c$ is a positive constant) 
and if this is wrong, what conditions can I pose on $f$ and $g$ to satisfy this inequality..? and if this is true, how can I prove it rigorously?

Answer (score 1):

First, we have
$$
\|\partial_x(I - \partial_x^2)^{-1}\partial_xh \|_{L^2(0,L)} 
\le c \|(I - \partial_x^2)^{-1}\partial_xh \|_{H^1(0,L)} .
$$
Define $z:=(I - \partial_x^2)^{-1}\partial_xh \in H^1_0(0,L)$. Then it satisfies the weak formulation
$$
\int_0^L \partial_x z\partial_x v + zv \ dx = \int_0^L \partial_x h \cdot v\ dx
$$
for all $v\in H^1_0(0,L)$. Partial integration on the right-hand side, and setting $v=z$ gives
$$
\int_0^L (\partial_x z)^2 + z^2 \ dx = -\int_0^L h \partial_x z\ dx.
$$
Hence we get
$$
\|z\|_{H^1}^2 \le \|h\|_{L^2(0,L)} \|\partial_xz\|_{L^2(0,L)}\le \|h\|_{L^2(0,L)} \|z\|_{H^1(0,L)},
$$
which shows $\|z\|_{H^1}\le \|h\|_{L^2(0,L)} $. And the claim is proven.

Note that the last step (the estimate of $z$ is nothing else than showing that $\|\partial_xh\|_{(H^1(0,L))^*}\le \|h\|_{L^2(0,L)}$.

Comment: Thnak you a lot sir......Thanks....good day...

Comment: @Gustav You should accept satisfying answers.

Comment: @daw Sir.when you made integration by part to get the weak formulation, how you knew that ${z_x}(L) = {z_x}(0) = 0$? thanks.

Comment: Misread your original question: we have $z$ and $v$ in $H^1_0(0,L)$, so $z(0)=z(L)=v(0)=v(L)=0$.

Comment: @daw sir. I'm sorry for the inconvenience and I appreciate your patience ..last question: you posed: $z = {(1 - \partial _x^2)^{ - 1}}{\partial _x}h$ , we know that $h(0)=h(L)=0$, is this implies that $z(L)=z(0)=0$ ?

Comment: $z(0)=z(L)=0$ is implied by $z\in H^1_0$.